# Deny permission to specific user of specific folder inside S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

In AWS S3, I have one bucket named "Environments" under that I have 4 folders named "sandbox", "staging", "prod1" and "prod2" respectively and the permission of the whole bucket is "public".

Now I want to restrict One AWS user named "developer" to write anything into "prod1" and "prod2" folder but it can view them.

Kindly help me out with this

Comment: So we're on the same page, are you trying to deny the "developer" from writing in these folders? Can the "developer" read anything from the bucket, or only from "prod1" and "prod2"?

Comment: What do you mean by "the whole bucket is public"? Are you using a Bucket Policy to achieve this? If so, please edit your question to show your Bucket Policy. (And if not, how have you configured the whole bucket to be public?) Also, _why_ is your bucket public? This is not normally recommended for a Development environment.

Comment: @Z_z_Z yes you are right.. I want to restrict "developer" user to do any modification in "prod1" and "prod2" folder

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I did not set the policies for that bucket, the developer before me said he gave "Grant Read Public Access to this bucket" permission, so Under "Access" column, in front of that Bucket name, Its permission says "Public"

Comment: I suggest you check whether a **Bucket Policy** has been assigned to the bucket. If the bucket contains any confidential or non-production content, you probably don't want it to be Public. Instead, grant permission on the **IAM Users or IAM Groups** so that specific job roles have appropriate access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create below policy and attach to a user **developer**

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                        "s3:GetBucketLocation",
                        "s3:ListAllMyBuckets"
                      ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::Environments",
                "arn:aws:s3:::Environments/sandbox/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::Environments/staging/*",
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

This policy allows to full permission to folder sandbox and staging, but restrict another folder to user **developer**

Comment: Thank you for your response, I will do it and let you know